# Difficult to increase the profile text in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I'm having trouble finding which file to change the css in Moodle tool. In pagia the "view profile", the data is cut by "..." I would vizualisar throughout.

Follow the link to the image:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ewzdf4mj4vwfmcc/sesi.JPG

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on it and press the INSPECT BUTTON in Chrome. You will see a panel that says wich file is the one been used.

Comment: This might help, but finding the real source file on the server might bring more difficulties. IIRC, moodle uses php. That means, the html does not reveal for sure, which php files might be of relevance. The question is nearly impossible to answer in its current form, if you do not happen to have experience with moodle - it's like showing a picture of a car and asking "why does it not start?"

Comment: I see, I have a lot of experience with other frameworks that do the same. My answer is very wrong then :) My suggestion is to put another question and ask something like: "How to debug CSS files before Moodle generates them", no?

Comment: Well, I would not say your answer is very wrong - it would be the first step to take for sure. It would then either take experience, documentation or intuition to find the corresponding source file of the html in question. I would not focus on css only; I would even tend to assume that the text is shortened by some PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

In moodle, There is chance to come mostly css from selected theme.

If the css is not coming from selected theme then it may from standard theme or from particular module.

Answer (score 0):

The css is put into one large file for performance. To switch this off, add this line to config.php

```
$CFG->themedesignermode = true;
```

Remove the line or set it to false after you have finished because it will make the site verrrry slow...
http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_theme#Theme_designer_mode

Refresh the profile page and now you can use inspect element in Chrome, it should show the original css file.

It seems to be this file /theme/canvas/style/core.css

Around lines 288 to 296 (In Moodle 2.5.4)

```
.userprofile dl dt {
    padding-left: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 2%;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 15%;
    clear: both;
}
```

So edit this file in your theme

```
/theme/yourthemename/style/core.css
```

And add this to override the default min-width.

```
.userprofile dl dt {
    min-width: 120px;
}
```

Refresh the profile page and it should display okay. 120px seems to be minimum for "Endereço de email" to be displayed in full.

Don't forget to remove this or set it to false after you have finished - config.php

```
$CFG->themedesignermode = false;
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas diretrizes, siga o que me orintou, mas eu não acho que essas linhas de código no arquivo core.css: . Userprofile dl dt {
    padding-left: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 2%;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 15%;
    clear: both;
}

Comment: qual a versão do Moodle você está usando?

Comment: Version 2.5
I can see this code when you inspect in Chrome, but I can not find the file core.css.

Comment: Oh, if the core file doesn't exist in your theme, then you can create it :) Create this in your theme /theme/yourthemename/style/core.css to overwrite the values in /theme/canvas/style/core.css

Comment: the core.css file this in my theme is this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbvmslmeh60t5b6/core.css